# In which intervals is the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 4}{x^2 - 7x + 10}$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

> In which intervals is the following function continuous?
>   $$f(x)= \frac{x^2−4}{x^2−7x+10}$$

I know the requirements for continuity, but I am not sure how I am supposed to find the limit for each possible value of $f(x)$.

Any help?

Comment: Hint: the function isn't defined for $x=2$ or $x=5.$

Comment: Yes I managed to figure that out. So does that mean it is continuous for all other values of x? Thank you!

Comment: Another hint is that products of continuous functions are continuous.

Comment: In $\mathbb R\setminus \{5\}$ because the root $2$ of the denominator is eliminated by equal root in the numerator.

Comment: @Piquito But in the given function, $x=2$ is not part of the domain either. For domain we have to consider the original function. Hence both $2$ and $5$ need to be taken out of the domain.

Comment: "but I am not sure how I am supposed to find the limit for each possible value of f(x)"  Then don't.

Answer (score 0):

The function that you have is a rational function. Therefore, like other rational functions, it is continuous across its domain. Thus, it is continuous on $(-\infty,2)\cup(2,5)\cup(5,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

As you can re-establish from the first principles,

- a constant function is continuous,
- the identity function is continuous,
- the sum of two continuous functions is continuous,
- the product of two continuous functions is continuous,
- the opposite of a continuous function is continuous,
- the reciprocal of a continuous function is continuous (where defined).

You can conclude.